# Using hostContext in UseKestrel dotnet 2.0 migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, migration

I'm in the process of migrating my dotnet 1.1.4 app to 2.0. In the ConfigureLogging() and ConfigureAppConfiguration() the first parameter is 'hostContext'. Does UseKestrel also have access to this? It looks like in the documentation it only has an 'options' parameter. If I already set the config in ConfigureAppConfiguration can I just store that in the functions scope through a variable? Or do i have to instantiate a new ConfigurationBuilder and set the path again to be able to use fields in my AppSettings.json file.

Comment: Edit:

I went digging in the code and it looks like theres an interface for it. I'm able to use the hostContext.Configuration.GetSection().

I lied, using the (hostContext, options) => {} does not work.

Comment: This was added in 2.1.